# Center-aligned masked UIImageView / Imitating Twitter & Facebook app's image views

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

Post title can be a little bit weird but here's what I'm looking forward to do:

[image]

Look at the image in the middle, it's displaying only a part of the original image. It's still high definition, not really cropped but only masked with the center of the image at the center of the view.

So basically they put a bigger image behind a smaller view (I did that for having circular imageviews in the past). But how can I achieve that particularly?

Is there any cocoapods or something to do so or should I get started doing it myself? Any suggestions on how to code-wisely build this?

The main goal here is to keep a static space to display images so they're always the same width/height. Doing this effect seems like a good way of achieving this.

EDIT: Here's a little sketch of an idea I just had to mimic that behavior:
[image]

Thanks a lot and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking what I think you're asking, you don't have to look far to find this functionality. Use UIView's built in `contentMode` property, specifically in this case, `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`.

```
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
```

Then to crop of the parts of the image extending out of the frame, be sure to use clipsToBounds:

```
[imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: Oh lol, really? I'll try, it's way simpler than I expected :P

Comment: Now my images are out of control! http://cl.ly/image/123U2705290S (Upper part should be a white container like the bottom one (with names and time). Does that change something about the framing/positioning of the imageviews? Thanks!

Comment: You're my hero! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, but make sure your image width and height is greater than the imageview,

```
imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeCenter;
imageView.clipsToBounds=YES;
imageView.clearsContextBeforeDrawing=NO;
```